# Unable to solve system of equations using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

When i tried to solve this system of equations 18 equations and 18 unknowns using numpy.linalg.solve(A,b) it showed an error like this:

```
>>numpy.linalg.solve(A,b)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 328, in solve
    raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
LinAlgError: Singular matrix`
```

Also, this is giving wrong answer compared to matlab and in matlab inverse is not raising any error as singular matrix

```
>>numpy.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
```

The equations:

```
A=[[  2.00000000e-05   1.04829508e-14   2.92236138e-24   4.99137993e-34
    5.52810194e-44   4.00873469e-54   1.84523284e-64   4.90835508e-75
    5.76100393e-86   5.99076740e-01   2.99538370e-01   2.24653778e-01
    1.87211481e-01   1.63810046e-01   1.47429042e-01   1.35143288e-01
    1.25490196e-01   1.17647059e-01],
 [  3.73770292e-01   2.09016082e-01   6.78532034e-02   1.39582215e-02
    1.89003753e-03   1.68885303e-04   9.62295375e-06   3.17769127e-07
    4.46104746e-09   2.20133438e-01   3.43958497e-01   3.09132700e-01
    2.41012794e-01   1.94347888e-01   1.66650637e-01   1.48719036e-01
    1.35807777e-01   1.25855315e-01],
 [  3.11663896e-01   3.06638455e-01   2.02332733e-01   8.94385710e-02
    2.66813026e-02   5.32020127e-03   6.81398496e-04   5.08044167e-05
    1.67948485e-06   7.07545654e-02   2.07209799e-01   2.96555487e-01
    2.92571675e-01   2.43843879e-01   1.98570296e-01   1.68671368e-01
    1.49520047e-01   1.36137091e-01],
 [  2.44042188e-01   2.93174990e-01   2.81499972e-01   1.97504125e-01
    9.74752167e-02   3.28394798e-02   7.18929918e-03   9.22549849e-04
    5.27171340e-05   1.90856412e-02   9.06567959e-02   1.99802807e-01
    2.77189118e-01   2.83255891e-01   2.43800895e-01   2.00174117e-01
    1.69378295e-01   1.49649602e-01],
 [  1.97866831e-01   2.44427869e-01   2.83430648e-01   2.71206641e-01
    1.95516338e-01   9.97711554e-02   3.37413845e-02   6.76442793e-03
    6.08038466e-04   4.05196947e-03   2.95793771e-02   9.79563619e-02
    1.96206492e-01   2.69960187e-01   2.80370309e-01   2.43866828e-01
    1.99997042e-01   1.68723418e-01],
 [  1.68723418e-01   1.99997042e-01   2.43866828e-01   2.80370309e-01
    2.69960187e-01   1.96206492e-01   9.79563620e-02   2.95793772e-02
    4.05196947e-03   6.08038465e-04   6.76442792e-03   3.37413845e-02
    9.97711553e-02   1.95516338e-01   2.71206641e-01   2.83430648e-01
    2.44427869e-01   1.97866831e-01],
 [  1.49649602e-01   1.69378295e-01   2.00174117e-01   2.43800894e-01
    2.83255891e-01   2.77189118e-01   1.99802807e-01   9.06567959e-02
    1.90856413e-02   5.27171338e-05   9.22549847e-04   7.18929917e-03
    3.28394797e-02   9.74752166e-02   1.97504125e-01   2.81499972e-01
    2.93174990e-01   2.44042188e-01],
 [  1.36137091e-01   1.49520047e-01   1.68671367e-01   1.98570296e-01
    2.43843879e-01   2.92571675e-01   2.96555487e-01   2.07209799e-01
    7.07545654e-02   1.67948484e-06   5.08044165e-05   6.81398494e-04
    5.32020126e-03   2.66813026e-02   8.94385709e-02   2.02332733e-01
    3.06638455e-01   3.11663896e-01],
 [  1.25855315e-01   1.35807777e-01   1.48719036e-01   1.66650637e-01
    1.94347888e-01   2.41012794e-01   3.09132700e-01   3.43958498e-01
    2.20133438e-01   4.46104727e-09   3.17769134e-07   9.62295367e-06
    1.68885302e-04   1.89003752e-03   1.39582215e-02   6.78532033e-02
    2.09016082e-01   3.73770292e-01],
 [  2.00000000e-05   1.04829508e-14   2.92236138e-24   4.99137993e-34
    5.52810194e-44   4.00873469e-54   1.84523284e-64   4.90835508e-75
    5.76100393e-86   5.99076740e-01   2.99538370e-01   2.24653778e-01
    1.87211481e-01   1.63810046e-01   1.47429042e-01   1.35143288e-01
    1.25490196e-01   1.17647059e-01],
 [  3.73770292e-01   2.09016082e-01   6.78532034e-02   1.39582215e-02
    1.89003753e-03   1.68885303e-04   9.62295375e-06   3.17769127e-07
    4.46104746e-09   2.20133438e-01   3.43958497e-01   3.09132700e-01
    2.41012794e-01   1.94347888e-01   1.66650637e-01   1.48719036e-01
    1.35807777e-01   1.25855315e-01],
 [  3.11663896e-01   3.06638455e-01   2.02332733e-01   8.94385710e-02
    2.66813026e-02   5.32020127e-03   6.81398496e-04   5.08044167e-05
    1.67948485e-06   7.07545654e-02   2.07209799e-01   2.96555487e-01
    2.92571675e-01   2.43843879e-01   1.98570296e-01   1.68671368e-01
    1.49520047e-01   1.36137091e-01],
 [  2.44042188e-01   2.93174990e-01   2.81499972e-01   1.97504125e-01
    9.74752167e-02   3.28394798e-02   7.18929918e-03   9.22549849e-04
    5.27171340e-05   1.90856412e-02   9.06567959e-02   1.99802807e-01
    2.77189118e-01   2.83255891e-01   2.43800895e-01   2.00174117e-01
    1.69378295e-01   1.49649602e-01],
 [  1.97866831e-01   2.44427869e-01   2.83430648e-01   2.71206641e-01
    1.95516338e-01   9.97711554e-02   3.37413845e-02   6.76442793e-03
    6.08038466e-04   4.05196947e-03   2.95793771e-02   9.79563619e-02
    1.96206492e-01   2.69960187e-01   2.80370309e-01   2.43866828e-01
    1.99997042e-01   1.68723418e-01],
 [  1.68723418e-01   1.99997042e-01   2.43866828e-01   2.80370309e-01
    2.69960187e-01   1.96206492e-01   9.79563620e-02   2.95793772e-02
    4.05196947e-03   6.08038465e-04   6.76442792e-03   3.37413845e-02
    9.97711553e-02   1.95516338e-01   2.71206641e-01   2.83430648e-01
    2.44427869e-01   1.97866831e-01],
 [  1.49649602e-01   1.69378295e-01   2.00174117e-01   2.43800894e-01
    2.83255891e-01   2.77189118e-01   1.99802807e-01   9.06567959e-02
    1.90856413e-02   5.27171338e-05   9.22549847e-04   7.18929917e-03
    3.28394797e-02   9.74752166e-02   1.97504125e-01   2.81499972e-01
    2.93174990e-01   2.44042188e-01],
 [  1.36137091e-01   1.49520047e-01   1.68671367e-01   1.98570296e-01
    2.43843879e-01   2.92571675e-01   2.96555487e-01   2.07209799e-01
    7.07545654e-02   1.67948484e-06   5.08044165e-05   6.81398494e-04
    5.32020126e-03   2.66813026e-02   8.94385709e-02   2.02332733e-01
    3.06638455e-01   3.11663896e-01],
 [  1.25855315e-01   1.35807777e-01   1.48719036e-01   1.66650637e-01
    1.94347888e-01   2.41012794e-01   3.09132700e-01   3.43958498e-01
    2.20133438e-01   4.46104727e-09   3.17769134e-07   9.62295367e-06
    1.68885302e-04   1.89003752e-03   1.39582215e-02   6.78532033e-02
    2.09016082e-01   3.73770292e-01]]
b=[ 0.4         0.49479209  0.64342066  0.82512366  1.0269273   1.23579182
  1.43570174  1.6028701   1.68969412  0.66666667  0.77260435  0.87408469
  0.97564512  1.07906283  1.18365629  1.28518028  1.37220606  1.41188186]
```

Comment: Well, your matrix is singular, so it's impossible to solve this equation system.  The matrix in Matlab might be just slightly different, or Matlab has less strict thresholds whether to consider a matrix singular.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving system of linear equations using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262329/solving-system-of-linear-equations-using-python)

Comment: well is there any way to find out the solution

Comment: Short answer, no. By definition, a set of linear equations with a singular matrix has no unique answer.

Comment: @004: Asking the same question again after it's closed isn't appropriate. Either edit the original question to address the reason why it was closed, or look for a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 15):

For whatever it's worth, you're getting confused with basic linear algebra.

You have 18 equations, but only 9 unique equations. The other 9 are linear combinations of other rows.

In other words, you have an under-determined problem.

This is immediately apparent if you take a quick look at your `A`....

[image]

This means that `A` is a singular matrix.

`lstsq` is essentially (though not explicitly) calculating the Moore-Penrose Pseudo-Inverse of the `A`.  That's why it works even though `A` is singular.

There is *absolutely no unique solution* to your problem.  However, you can still get an infinite number of *approximate* solutions.

Knowing which approximate solution to pick requires knowing something about your problem.  We need *a-priori* information.  This is basically what inverse theory is all about: How to incorporate a-priori information into underdetermined problems.

In your case, it looks like some of the columns are correlated as well. This means that we can probably reduce the dimensionality of the problem.  You're not going to be able to solve it with "normal" linear algebra, though. It's *not* an even-determined problem. You have 18 equations and only 9 solutions.

However, to reduce the dimensionality, we need more information about the *physical* problem that you're trying to solve.  What do your 18 variables represent?  Are there correlations between them? Should they be spatially correlated (i.e. should one value be close to the one after or not?)?

Here's code to generate the figure above, by the way...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=np.array([[2.00000000e-05, 1.04829508e-14, 2.92236138e-24, 4.99137993e-34,
             5.52810194e-44, 4.00873469e-54, 1.84523284e-64, 4.90835508e-75,
             5.76100393e-86, 5.99076740e-01, 2.99538370e-01, 2.24653778e-01,
             1.87211481e-01, 1.63810046e-01, 1.47429042e-01, 1.35143288e-01,
             1.25490196e-01, 1.17647059e-01],
             [3.73770292e-01, 2.09016082e-01, 6.78532034e-02, 1.39582215e-02,
             1.89003753e-03, 1.68885303e-04, 9.62295375e-06, 3.17769127e-07,
             4.46104746e-09, 2.20133438e-01, 3.43958497e-01, 3.09132700e-01,
             2.41012794e-01, 1.94347888e-01, 1.66650637e-01, 1.48719036e-01,
             1.35807777e-01, 1.25855315e-01],
             [3.11663896e-01, 3.06638455e-01, 2.02332733e-01, 8.94385710e-02,
             2.66813026e-02, 5.32020127e-03, 6.81398496e-04, 5.08044167e-05,
             1.67948485e-06, 7.07545654e-02, 2.07209799e-01, 2.96555487e-01,
             2.92571675e-01, 2.43843879e-01, 1.98570296e-01, 1.68671368e-01,
             1.49520047e-01, 1.36137091e-01],
             [2.44042188e-01, 2.93174990e-01, 2.81499972e-01, 1.97504125e-01,
             9.74752167e-02, 3.28394798e-02, 7.18929918e-03, 9.22549849e-04,
             5.27171340e-05, 1.90856412e-02, 9.06567959e-02, 1.99802807e-01,
             2.77189118e-01, 2.83255891e-01, 2.43800895e-01, 2.00174117e-01,
             1.69378295e-01, 1.49649602e-01],
             [1.97866831e-01, 2.44427869e-01, 2.83430648e-01, 2.71206641e-01,
             1.95516338e-01, 9.97711554e-02, 3.37413845e-02, 6.76442793e-03,
             6.08038466e-04, 4.05196947e-03, 2.95793771e-02, 9.79563619e-02,
             1.96206492e-01, 2.69960187e-01, 2.80370309e-01, 2.43866828e-01,
             1.99997042e-01, 1.68723418e-01],
             [1.68723418e-01, 1.99997042e-01, 2.43866828e-01, 2.80370309e-01,
             2.69960187e-01, 1.96206492e-01, 9.79563620e-02, 2.95793772e-02,
             4.05196947e-03, 6.08038465e-04, 6.76442792e-03, 3.37413845e-02,
             9.97711553e-02, 1.95516338e-01, 2.71206641e-01, 2.83430648e-01,
             2.44427869e-01, 1.97866831e-01],
             [1.49649602e-01, 1.69378295e-01, 2.00174117e-01, 2.43800894e-01,
             2.83255891e-01, 2.77189118e-01, 1.99802807e-01, 9.06567959e-02,
             1.90856413e-02, 5.27171338e-05, 9.22549847e-04, 7.18929917e-03,
             3.28394797e-02, 9.74752166e-02, 1.97504125e-01, 2.81499972e-01,
             2.93174990e-01, 2.44042188e-01],
             [1.36137091e-01, 1.49520047e-01, 1.68671367e-01, 1.98570296e-01,
             2.43843879e-01, 2.92571675e-01, 2.96555487e-01, 2.07209799e-01,
             7.07545654e-02, 1.67948484e-06, 5.08044165e-05, 6.81398494e-04,
             5.32020126e-03, 2.66813026e-02, 8.94385709e-02, 2.02332733e-01,
             3.06638455e-01, 3.11663896e-01],
             [1.25855315e-01, 1.35807777e-01, 1.48719036e-01, 1.66650637e-01,
             1.94347888e-01, 2.41012794e-01, 3.09132700e-01, 3.43958498e-01,
             2.20133438e-01, 4.46104727e-09, 3.17769134e-07, 9.62295367e-06,
             1.68885302e-04, 1.89003752e-03, 1.39582215e-02, 6.78532033e-02,
             2.09016082e-01, 3.73770292e-01],
             [2.00000000e-05, 1.04829508e-14, 2.92236138e-24, 4.99137993e-34,
             5.52810194e-44, 4.00873469e-54, 1.84523284e-64, 4.90835508e-75,
             5.76100393e-86, 5.99076740e-01, 2.99538370e-01, 2.24653778e-01,
             1.87211481e-01, 1.63810046e-01, 1.47429042e-01, 1.35143288e-01,
             1.25490196e-01, 1.17647059e-01],
             [3.73770292e-01, 2.09016082e-01, 6.78532034e-02, 1.39582215e-02,
             1.89003753e-03, 1.68885303e-04, 9.62295375e-06, 3.17769127e-07,
             4.46104746e-09, 2.20133438e-01, 3.43958497e-01, 3.09132700e-01,
             2.41012794e-01, 1.94347888e-01, 1.66650637e-01, 1.48719036e-01,
             1.35807777e-01, 1.25855315e-01],
             [3.11663896e-01, 3.06638455e-01, 2.02332733e-01, 8.94385710e-02,
             2.66813026e-02, 5.32020127e-03, 6.81398496e-04, 5.08044167e-05,
             1.67948485e-06, 7.07545654e-02, 2.07209799e-01, 2.96555487e-01,
             2.92571675e-01, 2.43843879e-01, 1.98570296e-01, 1.68671368e-01,
             1.49520047e-01, 1.36137091e-01],
             [2.44042188e-01, 2.93174990e-01, 2.81499972e-01, 1.97504125e-01,
             9.74752167e-02, 3.28394798e-02, 7.18929918e-03, 9.22549849e-04,
             5.27171340e-05, 1.90856412e-02, 9.06567959e-02, 1.99802807e-01,
             2.77189118e-01, 2.83255891e-01, 2.43800895e-01, 2.00174117e-01,
             1.69378295e-01, 1.49649602e-01],
             [1.97866831e-01, 2.44427869e-01, 2.83430648e-01, 2.71206641e-01,
             1.95516338e-01, 9.97711554e-02, 3.37413845e-02, 6.76442793e-03,
             6.08038466e-04, 4.05196947e-03, 2.95793771e-02, 9.79563619e-02,
             1.96206492e-01, 2.69960187e-01, 2.80370309e-01, 2.43866828e-01,
             1.99997042e-01, 1.68723418e-01],
             [1.68723418e-01, 1.99997042e-01, 2.43866828e-01, 2.80370309e-01,
             2.69960187e-01, 1.96206492e-01, 9.79563620e-02, 2.95793772e-02,
             4.05196947e-03, 6.08038465e-04, 6.76442792e-03, 3.37413845e-02,
             9.97711553e-02, 1.95516338e-01, 2.71206641e-01, 2.83430648e-01,
             2.44427869e-01, 1.97866831e-01],
             [1.49649602e-01, 1.69378295e-01, 2.00174117e-01, 2.43800894e-01,
             2.83255891e-01, 2.77189118e-01, 1.99802807e-01, 9.06567959e-02,
             1.90856413e-02, 5.27171338e-05, 9.22549847e-04, 7.18929917e-03,
             3.28394797e-02, 9.74752166e-02, 1.97504125e-01, 2.81499972e-01,
             2.93174990e-01, 2.44042188e-01],
             [1.36137091e-01, 1.49520047e-01, 1.68671367e-01, 1.98570296e-01,
             2.43843879e-01, 2.92571675e-01, 2.96555487e-01, 2.07209799e-01,
             7.07545654e-02, 1.67948484e-06, 5.08044165e-05, 6.81398494e-04,
             5.32020126e-03, 2.66813026e-02, 8.94385709e-02, 2.02332733e-01,
             3.06638455e-01, 3.11663896e-01],
             [1.25855315e-01, 1.35807777e-01, 1.48719036e-01, 1.66650637e-01,
             1.94347888e-01, 2.41012794e-01, 3.09132700e-01, 3.43958498e-01,
             2.20133438e-01, 4.46104727e-09, 3.17769134e-07, 9.62295367e-06,
             1.68885302e-04, 1.89003752e-03, 1.39582215e-02, 6.78532033e-02,
             2.09016082e-01, 3.73770292e-01]])
b = np.array([0.4, 0.49479209, 0.64342066, 0.82512366, 1.0269273, 1.23579182,
        1.43570174, 1.6028701, 1.68969412, 0.66666667, 0.77260435, 0.87408469,
        0.97564512, 1.07906283, 1.18365629, 1.28518028, 1.37220606, 1.41188186])

plt.matshow(A)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/81577017/Journal-Paper   this is the problem that i have been trying to write the code for and the matrices shown above are the one that are generated for the example 1

Comment: The paper specifically mentions choosing some of the arbitrary variables such that the matrix isn't singular... Perhaps you should choose another set of `x_{j}`'s?  Have a look at the third page.

Comment: that helps a lot but I have a doubt why matlab is able to solve the same system of equations and whynot numpy?? with the same values of x_j

Comment: Are you sure you're actually entering the same values?  Matlab can't solve what you've entered above.  I've tried it.  It tells me it's a singular matrix.